# What to do when reviewing a good Q/A?

Tags: support, review

Most of the Questions or Answers (Q/A) on the [review queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts) have *something* to improve (title, tags, poor content formatting, etc.), but sometimes are Q/A that are, not just well written and I don't see anything to improve there, **but also are useful** so I want to *upvote* it.

So the main question is, **What should I do in such a case**?

- Should I upvote it and press *Skip* ?
- Should I upvote it and press *I'm Done* ?
- Or should I press *No Action Needed* and no upvote it from the review window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Upvote and press *Skip*

Don't do this.

Upvoting is a legitimate review, why would you skip it then? Skipping it does not count it as reviewed by you, and just keeps it in the pool.

Skippping should mostly be used when you're not sure.

For example: You remember something similar being around, so it might be a dupe, but you can't find it / pinpoint it -> Skip it. It feels like this should be closed, or dealt with, but you can't really nail down *how* or *why*.

## Upvote and press *I'm Done*

If you believe that the upvote is all that's needed, then do this.

*I'm Done* is really you marking it as reviewed, so, if the Upvote is a sufficient review in your eyes, go with it!

## *No Action Needed!*

This is mostly for posts that are "fine", just neither upvote-worthy, nor in need of improvement. If you feel uncomfortable with upvoting it, because it feels not "perfect" in the sense of "This deserves an upvote right now!", use this.

Comment: I'm agree with you with `Skip`, because it will continue going around the queue.